# Matplotlib x-axis have n values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a big dataframe but the datas are not at the same time. Sometimes every few seconds, sometimes every some minutes.

I'm using `plt.xticks(x[::24], rotation=30)` (one label every 24 values), but sometimes i have a lot of labels on x axis. So, I want to have 12 (for example) labels.

Is it possible on x-axis labels have n values (for example n=12)?

Comment: what is the datatype of each element in x?

Comment: @TrườngThuậnNguyễn is object using `df.info()`.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of try and error, finally I found the solution.

First, take the length of the dataframe.

```
nval = len(df.T1)
```

Second calculate the number of values (as step in xticks). Divide the number of dataframe length by the number of ticks you want in your diagram (for me is 8). In most of cases this number is float.

```
nValues = nval / 8
```

Third, because xticks need integer, convert the previous variable (nValues) to integer.

```
nValues = int(nValues)
```

The final step is to add nValues to:

```
plt.xticks(x[::nValues])
```

Following previous, you can create a matplotlib graph having as much ticks as you want + 1. First time plus the number of ticks you want.

WARNING:

1. If your divided value (8 for me) is bigger than dataframe length, then you can't  transfer value integer.
2. I your divided value is 1, then you will have ONLY the first time of your dataframe and no more ticks.